# Number of trees using cforest in caret

Tags: r, random-forest, caret

I have read some of the previous posts about this issue and I still do not understand how caret decides on the number of trees when you use the `model=cforest` from party package.
I know that at certain threshold there is no use of building more trees, but how is this optimal number calculated? Is it a default?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50210/caret-and-randomforest-number-of-trees?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

The `train` function only varies the tuning parameters and the other function arguments are left to their defaults. In this case, `?cforest_control` reports that `ntree = 500`.

Please take a look at the [caret homepage](http://caret.r-forge.r-project.org/). There is a lot of detail.

Max